# NSD/BIND -- how to log dns resolver ip and edns

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, resolv.conf, nsd

Do BIND and NSD support verbose logging of the DNS resolver's ip address for a query?

If the vanilla releases do support that, what's the best practice for enabling/configuring that functionality. If this feature is not available in the vanilla releases, are there extensions out there?

Comment: The title refers to "edns", is the implication of that to log [EDNS Client Subnet](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-dnsop-edns-client-subnet/) values?  At least BIND has query logging (including client address) but I don't think there's anything for ECS values.